# Parse JSON objects correctly

Tags: c#, json, class, object

I have a RootObject and several other JSON objects I have already translated into classes correctly from this JSON. And the I get to this and I am stuck. What I want is the first to be the key and the second the value, but when I paste it in Visual Studio it generates classes for each one separately.
JSON part:

```
[{"Images":[
{"name":"someimageurl"},
{"name1":"someimageurl1"},
{"name2":"someimageurl2"},
{"name3":"someimageurl3"},
{"name4":"someimageurl4"}]}]
```

What I have, but doesn't work that well is:

```
public List<Dictionary<string,string>> Images { get; set; }
```

What I want is to translate this JSON as if it was written:

```
[
{
    "Images": [
        {"key": "name" },{"value": "someimageurl"},
        {"key": "name1"},{"value": "someimageurl1"},
        {"key": "name2"},{"value": "someimageurl2"},
        {"key": "name3"},{"value": "someimageurl3"},
        {"key": "name4"},{"value": "someimageurl4"}
    ]
}
```

]

PS:I can't change the JSON I receive it comes from a webservice. I have managed to parse the rest of my Json without a problem. It doesn't return an error, it just doesn't return the values the way I want them in order to work with them. Images is under my RootObject. It is an array (?) of pairs. The first part is the name I want to use as key and the second is the value. I want to be able to search for the key and get the value but since the "key" changes name the classes that get generated from visual studio (and other tools) are in a wrong format to be used the way I want them.

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried something? Googling for "c# json" will return the answer immediatelly

Comment: *What I have, but doesn't work that well* What does doesn't work that well mean?

Comment: It means everything I tried (keypairValues instead of Dictionary, Dictionary etc returns either null or a string with both the parameter I want to be set as key and the value.

@PanagiotisKanavos If I am here it means I have googled and seen at least two pages (in this case more) or results and answers, but thank you for your valuable input.

Comment: @Redhead the very first result tells you that you should use Json.NET. As it is, the question doesn't describe any specific problem. If you've tried with Json.NET but received an error, post the code and the error.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use Json.Net. I also say that I have managed to parse the rest of my Json without a problem.It doesn't return an error, it just doesn't return the values the way I want them in order to work with them. If I posted the entire of my code this question would be huge, so I post the problematic part. Images is under my RootObject. It is an array (?) of pairs. The first part is the name I want to use as key and the second is the value. I want to be able to search for the key and get the value.

Comment: Please put all this in the question, not the comments. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in Help to see what is expected from a good question